# Is it possible to propagate markup tags to a usercontrol in WPF?

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, telerik

First of all, I'm pretty new to WPF, so sorry if this is an obvious question. I have researched about this subject and found nothing, maybe I haven't used the correct or appropiate words. I will appreciate your help in the matter.

My problem is "simple":
I have a Telerik RadGridView in a usercontrol in my application. This contains the RadGridView, a pair of buttons, and some extra functions, and will be quite generic in all the scope of the program, so I need to extend to the control some of the grid functionalities.

Have created DependencyProperties binded to some of the grid properties and they work perfect. But the problem comes where I have a dynamic collection of values to a property binded to the grid via XAML.

You'll understand this with an example.
RadGridView can group all its rows by a certain column or columns. The way of doing this is:

```
<telerik:RadGridView>
     <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumn1"/>
     <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumn2"/>
     <!--...-->
     <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumnN"/>
</telerik:RadGridView>
```

So I want to have a control that have the same functionality and propagates to the inner grid, something like

```
<UserControls:RadGridControl>
     <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumn1"/>
     <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumn2"/>
     <!--...-->
     <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumnN"/>
</UserControls:RadGridControl>
```

And to propagate the GroupDescriptors to the RadGridView inside the usercontrol the same way as the first bit of code.
Is it possible to do this via XAML?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

First add a property of the type you want to propagate in your user control. In your case:

```
Telerik.Windows.Data.GroupDescriptorCollection GroupDescriptors
{
    get
    {
        return mygridview.GroupDescriptors;
    }
}
```

Now you can do this when you want to change the group discriptors outside of the control.

```
<local:MyUserControl>
    <local:MyUserControl.GroupDescriptors>
        <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumn1"/>
        <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumn2"/>
        <!--...-->
        <telerik:GroupDescriptor Member="groupingColumnN"/>
    </local:MyUserControl.GroupDescriptors>
</local:MyUserControl>
```

Comment: Oh, it was quite simple! Just some typo ¿mistake? in your answer: I replaced <local:MyUserControl:GroupDescriptors> per <local:MyUserControl.GroupDescriptors> in order to work.

I still don't understand it at all, though. If you create inner elements inside a collection tag, WPF automatically adds them to the collection? And what if the "adding way" is not standard? Doesn't matter?

Thanks again :)

Comment: It's the same as using it in the RadGridView. There you define GroupDescriptors in <telerik:RadGridView.GroupDescriptors>. So you just expose it outside of the control.

Comment: Yeah, of course, it makes sense.

So it's not possible to "create" the addition of those elements to a custom list via XAML in such an easy way, right?